# Sitecore - Webforms For Marketers Form - Use ReadQueryString Option

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

When one has added a WFFM form to a Sitecore Item, you can go to the Presentation Details and click on Form. There you'll see an option called `ReadQueryString - Reads initial values from the url query string.`

My form has a few fields, one of which being `Email`. I tried adding `?Email=test` to the URL of the page that hosts this form, but the value is not being picked up. Am I correctly understanding the intended purpose of this option? Am I using it correctly?

Sitecore version 6.5; Web Forms for Marketers version 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You understood the purpose correctly, when that option is checked the form's initial values are read from the querystring.
I have used this in my project and it works fine.

Make sure that you are using the field's **item name** in the querystring, not the displayname or title.
Also double check if you published the item after checking the `ReadQueryString` option.

Comment: Thanks Rudd! How can I find the field's item name as opposed to it's display name? When I click on the fields, I only see the options for default value, help text, validation rules, etc.

Comment: If you go to your form in the Content Editor you will see it has child items. Those are its fields. If you click on one, you can see the Item Name in the Quick Info section.

Comment: Of course Ruud, I should have thought of that. I was coming at this purely from the WFFM Form Designer window. Thanks!